# JSLint: How to flag code as being wrong

Tags: javascript, jslint

I would like to is flag some piece of code to come back to later.  The code is seriously violating our design and I want to ensure that I see it every time I run JSHint until I fix it.

Just as an example suppose that to get something else working I change this code:

```
addTwoNumbers: function(numberOne, numberTwo){
    return numberOne+numberTwo;
}
```

To this:

```
addTwoNumbers: function(numberOne, numberTwo){
    return 11;
}
```

JSLint has no problems with these changes, but clearly they will cause me some trouble later.  What would like to do is something like this:

```
addTwoNumbers: function(numberOne, numberTwo){
    /* jslint fail */
    return 11;
}
```

This way when I run JSLint before committing I will see that I have done something I probably shouldn't.

Alternately, if I am planning on committing the code (bad idea) and coming back to it in a couple weeks, I want to be warned frequently by JSHint.

---

I know that I can use the "Unexpected TODO comment" but my team (me included) uses TODO very liberally.  Another method would be preferred.

More info on: [Unexpected TODO comment](http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-todo-comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a coding style and not a language fault, and recently JSHint has taken the decision to not implement coding style options in the linter.

I'm not sure of the state of development, but it may be/become possible to write extensions to JSHint to enforce one's own coding style.

Though, what you're asking is done since programming and editors exist:

```
addTwoNumbers: function(numberOne, numberTwo){
    return 11; // TODO bad implementation, change it!
}
```

and have your editor highlight the comment in yellow and red, add a `/!\` in the line number column, and have it list it along with the warnings of your linter!

But that's *not* JSHint's job, or even a linter's job to check that kind of things!

Comment: Good point about using an editor.  Unfortunately, what I would like to do is have something that my entire team could use.  We all use different editors (vim, eclipse, sublime, etc).  Since we all share the same .jshint file and we all run jshint as a grunt task it is easy to setup something backpacking on jshint.  I upvoted your answer but am going to leave the question open for a bit and see if I can get another answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am leaving this here partly as a note to myself and partly for anyone else who has this issue.

If you are using grunt to invoke jslint, you can also use [grunt-todo](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-todo).  This allows you to define tags in your project and then it will list the tags on build/grunt.  It has some built in tags by default and you can add your own.  I think you should even be able to configure your release build to fail if there are specific tags in the code base.